# How to calculate total optimal connection count and find DB instance type to use?

Tags: database, mongodb, postgresql, database-connection, aws-documentdb

How can I calculate the optimal total connection count from my service to the my DB endpoint? Is there a basic formula based on expected number of queries per second and CPU and IO taken by each query?

Similarly, is there a formula to calculate the optimal database instance type/size to use based on traffic patterns and query characteristics (CPU, IO consumed or latency of query)?

I will be using this to create the connection pool in my service. I'm assuming that if my service has N hosts then per host the connection pool size need to be the total optimal connection count divided by N.

Note: By instance type I mean similar to AWS EC2 instance type which provides info on vCPU and memory (RAM)

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to sizing the database machine, the key measure is the number of concurrently active database sessions. Since each active session corresponds to at least one database process, you have to provide enough CPU power and I/O capacity to handle them concurrently.

An estimate for that number would be `average query duration in seconds * number of queries per second`. You have to have at least that many cores, and your I/O system has to be able to handle that many concurrent I/O requests.

When it comes to dimensioning a connection pool, you also have to factor in the time that the database spends idle in a transaction while waiting for the next statement from the client.

The maximal connection pool size would be `number of concurrent queries the database can handle / (transaction busy ratio * average query duration in seconds * number of queries per second)`. The `transaction busy ratio` is `active time for a transaction / total time for a transaction` - so if all your transactions consist of only a single statement (which means that no time is spent waiting for the next statement in a transaction), that ratio would be 1.

In practice, it is difficult to estimate or measure the ideal pool size, and you have to run load tests to see how big you can make the pool without overloading your database.